# Joomla 3 - List All Categories override

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I would like to override the default List All Categories view in my Joomla 3 installation. I have this article's structure:

- Fish

  - White Shark
  - Lemon Shark
  - Dolphin
  - Whale Shark
- Flowers

  - Daffodil
  - Red Rose
  - Tulip
  - Gillyflower

The default List All Categories shows the category name followed by the number af all articles within that category.

[Default List All Categories view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usuv2.png)

I would like it to show the name of the category followed by all the articles within that category displayed as a Category List.

[Customized / overriden List All Categories view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLW9L.png)

I would like to know which default.php file to copy to my HTML/com_content/categories folder and what code changes to make, to achieve my goal.

Thank you for your help!